# Most performant way to compare file paths from DB query results and filesystem

Tags: java, c#, database, powershell, file

I've got a database where filepaths are stored e.g. in this way:

```
SELECT filepath FROM content
-- results: 
-- D:\eb3097ef-f3d9-463f-bda5-d3c737acf767\7b34d48e-f176-11ec-8ea0-0242ac120002
-- D:\eb3097ef-f3d9-463f-bda5-d3c737acf767\7b34d48e-f176-11ec-8ea0-0242ac120003
-- D:\b4198a77-4c66-4edb-bef9-548546c0e01f\2e565c87-861f-46a8-9c75-e5861f2b087f\..
...
```

All directory and file names are UUIDs (36 digits).
I know the root directory containing all the files and have to check if

1. all files resulted from db query exist in the root directory
2. there are any files in the root directory but not in the db

So I basically have to compare filesystem with my db and vice versa. I need to know exactly where a certain file is missing (db or fs) and not just the fact that it's missing.

My solution so far was simple. Exporting all db query results to a txt file manually, then looping through the root directory using PowerShell `gci`. Afterwards I parsed both outputs into `Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]` and finally did an `SymmetricExceptWith` on them. This was actually ok performant (~10-15min. for 1.700.000 files having ~1TB total / CPU Usage ~40%), but trying like 2TB+ brought the system to its knees.

Whats the best and **most performant** way to achieve this? Java based solution is preferred but C# or even PS is also fine.

Comment: Is the timing pure based on the `SymmetricExceptWith` or also includes database transaction and `gci`? Generally, the concept sounds ok but the implementation might be wrong, therefore you will need to share what you actually did (some of your code).

Comment: Timing is based on `gci` and `SymmetricExceptWith`. Finally I also append all differences into a file but mostly there will be an amount of less than 1% of total data count, which means, there are only a few lines written to file.

Comment: If you have to list the existing file paths regularly, then `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($folderPath,'*','AllDirectories')` runs about 10x faster than `gci`

Answer (score 2):

What does `~1TB` files mean? Presumably, 'an unknown amount of files whose size adds up to about 1 terabyte' but that's utterly irrelevant, the only relevant question is how many files there are.

The general principle that should be fastest:

1. Obtain all filepaths from the database, stripped down to the minimum (i.e. if they *all* start with `D:\data\` get rid of that).
2. Sort it.
3. Obtain all filepaths from disk (i.e. the result of `ls`), stripped down.
4. Sort it.
5. Loop once through both simultaneously, generating the list of mismatches as you loop.

Step 1 is O(n), step 2 is O(n log n), step 3 is O(m), step 4 is O(m log m), step 5 is O(max(n, m)).

Assuming `n` and `m` are similarly sized, that's `O(3n+2n*log(n))` which is just `O(n log n)` and algorithmically speaking I don't think you can do better; that should do fine even if you have millions of files.

However, there are 2 aspects to this whose performance is dependent on outside factors and can be significant:

1. How fast is 'list all files'? Once you have a dir with millions of files, this can be notoriously slow: File systems are generally not designed to do this quickly, and if they are, often various APIs to query this stuff isn't efficient. I would *think* `Files.newDirectoryStream` is fast, but I can't guarantee it for you. It's possible that a low level `bash -c ls >foo.txt` will be faster. Probably not. You're just going to have to test this out: Find a bunch of ways to list files in a dir and figure out which one is actually fast.
2. How fast is 'query all paths'? This depends on your DB engine and the indices you have. I can easily see how `SELECT SUBSTR(p, 8) FROM (SELECT filepath p FROM content ORDER BY filepath);` is in fact the fastest way to pull this data from the DB, and I can also see how that will be crazy slow. Depends on your DB engine, the optimizer, and the indices you set up. You'll have to go experiment with *just* this step too. There are a ton of variables: Which indices do you have, who does the 'stripping' of the path? Just selecting and ordering by `SUBSTR(...)` may in fact be really slow (generally those won't use an index even if one exists. But maybe if you have a function index it does go quickly). Who does the sorting? Maybe it's faster to just let the DB toss the data to your java app and do the sorting java-side. Maybe not. All stuff to test.
3. Does it all fit in memory? Step 5 will be orders of magnitude faster if both lists are entirely in memory. If you actually have so incredulously many files that the memory load of just the file names on its own is 1 terabyte, then obviously it won't (but we're talking about trillions of files, that does not seem likely) - so I doubt it's that bad. 100 million files, each file's name being something simple like `file1.txt`, containing only ascii, is only 20*100 million = ~2GB worth of memory for the strings. Two lists total, so that's ~4GB. Easily fits in memory, and that's **100 million file names**. Surely you don't have more than that many. I'm not sure storing 100 million files in a single dir is a good idea.

### How do you compare 2 lists in one loop?

Think about it, write down on a whiteboard or a piece of paper these 2 lists, vertically (line 1: Apple, line 2: Banana, etc), then put the second list vertically right next to it (so both Apple are on the same line).

[Apple, Banana, Cherry, Kumquat, Pepper, Pear]

[Apple, Banana, Kumquat, Orange, Pepper, Pear]

Now imagine how one would do this. It's quite simple: Make a little token (a torn off piece of paper for example); this is the 'pointer' make one for each list. Put the 'pointer' on the first entry of each list.

Now your algorithm is simple:

1. If both pointers are pointing at the same string, then do nothing (that entry is in both and thus already synced, no need for action) - just *advanced both pointers down to the next entry*.
2. Otherwise, check which of the 2 strings is 'lower' (sorts below the other). That one is unique - register accordingly, and then advance *only* that pointer.

That's really it - you just need to add some extra logic for what happens if one of the 2 pointers is at the end (that means the other one is neccessarily unique) and add code that if both are at the end, you're done with the algorithm.

In this example, you'd skip past Apple and Banana, then..

Cherry is lower than Kumquat, so Cherry is unique in the first list. Then you advance just that pointer. Next you compare Kumquat and Kumquat, so you advance both, then you notice Orange is below Pepper, so Orange is unique, and then the algorithm finishes up, concluding that list 1 has a unique Cherry, list 2 had a unique Orange. All in `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ive edited my post and added information. There are around 1.700.000 files. Dir and file names are UUIDs.